# Whats the equivalent of Java Arrays.copyOfRange in Go?

Tags: java, arrays, go

I'm working on the creating a Java library that deals with management of Arrays. Is there an equivalent of Arrays.copyOfRange in Go?

Comment: You might want to explain what the method does, as the question currently (unnecessarily) requires both Go and Java knowledge to answer, which reduces the likelihood of getting an answer as well as the future value of the question.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy

Answer (score 5):

A simple one-liner would be (index check omitted):

```
func copyOfRange(src []byte, from, to int) []byte {
    return append([]byte(nil), src[from:to]...)
}
```

A simple [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) "almost" does the job, but since Java's `Arrays.copyOfRange()` returns a copy independent from the source, we need to copy the slicing result to a new slice (because the result of slicing will share the backing array).

We can do that by allocating one with [`make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make), and use the builtin [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy), or simply use [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) to append it to an empty or `nil` slice, which will take care of the allocation and copying.

Example using the above function:

```
src := []byte{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
dst := copyOfRange(src, 2, 4)
fmt.Println(dst)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nXgYWaAFB_D)):

```
[2 3]
```

For completeness, this is how it would look like with `make()` and `copy()`:

```
func copyOfRange2(src []byte, from, to int) []byte {
    src = src[from:to]
    dst := make([]byte, len(src))
    copy(dst, src)
    return dst
}
```

One thing to note here: the builtin `append()` allocates more space than needed, thinking of future growth. So if you don't plan to "grow" the returned slice, `copyOfRange2()` is a better option.

See this comparison:

```
dst := copyOfRange(src, 2, 4)
fmt.Println(dst, cap(dst))

dst = copyOfRange2(src, 2, 4)
fmt.Println(dst, cap(dst))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OI_TsGDzuo4)):

```
[2 3] 8
[2 3] 2
```

As you can see, `append()` (inside `copyOfRange()`) allocated a backing array with a size of `8`, while in our `copyOfRange2()` we explicitly allocated a slice (and backing array) of size `2`.